# How to update slim API helper in PHP?

Tags: php, server, xampp

I'm working with an organaization so, I can't share my code snapt but I can share some error message that occure while I'm trying to update slim api in php v8.2.

Error messages:

```
Deprecated: Return type of Pimple\Container::offsetExists($id) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php on line 128

Deprecated: Return type of Pimple\Container::offsetGet($id) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php on line 93

Deprecated: Return type of Pimple\Container::offsetSet($id, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php on line 74

Deprecated: Return type of Pimple\Container::offsetUnset($id) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\pimple\pimple\src\Pimple\Container.php on line 138

Deprecated: Return type of Slim\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\slim\slim\Slim\Collection.php on line 141

Deprecated: Return type of Slim\Collection::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\slim\slim\Slim\Collection.php on line 153

Deprecated: Return type of Slim\Collection::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\slim\slim\Slim\Collection.php on line 164

Deprecated: Return type of Slim\Collection::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat_discount_tool\helpers\ipm-api\slim\slim\Slim\Collection.php on line 174
```

I'm trying to match my project with a php new version and getting an error while executing my old php code due to version updating.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your code base to match PHP version. Go through all composer packages and check every package to support PHP8.2

E.g. update Slim to [4.11.0](https://packagist.org/packages/slim/slim#4.11.0)

*OR*

Since these are not errors but deprecations (that will be shown once per request), you can disable deprecations from showing up:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```